# Using WIX to install a WMI provider

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wmi

I have developed a WMI provider in C# using the System.Management.Instrumentation namespace.  I need to install the provider into the GAC and register it with the WMI repository using MSI.  How might I accomplish this with WIX?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a CustomAction to register the WMI provider. We've thought about adding a standard CustomAction to the WiX toolset to support this but haven't had the time to do so yet.  Probably quite a bit of work.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without invoking InstallUtil.exe?  We want to refrain from using InstallUtil because it lacks support for rollback scenarios.

Comment: Yeah, InstallUtil.exe should never be used for CustomActions. Using DLLs that read tables from the MSI are the way that all the WiX toolset CustomActions are implemented.  You might check them out.

Comment: For those who is wondering whether it is still not supported, here's a link to github issue: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/846

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the AssemblyInstaller class in the .NET framework.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller_methods.aspx

You can create a managed custom action that uses the Install() and Commit() methods to generate a mof of your WMI provider and install it.  You can also use the Uninstall() and Commit() methods in your uninstall CustomAction.

I don't know if this is the official recommended way to accomplish this task.  It kind of feels like self-registration which I don't like to use in an installer.  However, the only way I know of to get static class/instance definitions registered in WMI's database is to compile a MOF file.  The MOF containing your class/instance information is where your WMI provider assembly is referenced.

The AssemblyInstaller class knows how to generate and compile your MOF file for you.  There is also a native API (IMofCompiler::CompileFile): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390867(v=vs.85).aspx that can be used to compile your MOF file.